# MYSQL query fetching DATA from two table using IN method one as composition of multiple data

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

one as `td_job` which has these structure

```
|---------|-----------|---------------|----------------|
| job_id  | job_title |   job_skill   |   job_desc     |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|   1     |  Job 1    |     1,2       |                |
|------------------------------------------------------|
|   2     |   Job 2   |     1,3       |                |
|------------------------------------------------------|
```

The other Table is `td_skill` which is this one

```
    |---------|-----------|--------------|
    |skill_id |skill_title| skill_slug   |
    |---------------------|--------------|
    |   1     |   PHP     |  1-PHP       |
    |---------------------|--------------|
    |   2     |  JQuery   |  2-JQuery    |
    |---------------------|--------------|
```

now the job_skill in td_job is actualy the list of skill_id from td_skill

that means the job_id 1 has two skills associated with it, skill_id 1 and skill_id 2

Now I am writing a query which is this one

```
SELECT * FROM td_job,td_skill 
WHERE td_skill.skill_id IN (SELECT td_job.job_skill FROM td_job)
      AND td_skill.skill_slug LIKE '%$job_param%'
```

Now when the $job_param is PHP it returns one row, but if $job_param is JQuery it returns empty row.

I want to know where is the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you are storing a list of id's in a column rather than in an association/junction table.  You should have another table, `JobSkills` with one row per job/skill combination.

The second and third problems are that you don't seem to understand how joins work nor how `in` with a subquery works.  In any case, the query that you seem to want is more like:

```
SELECT *
FROM td_job j join
     td_skill s
     on find_in_set(s.skill_id, j.job_skill) > 0 and
        s.skill_slug LIKE '%$job_param%';
```

Very bad database design.  You should fix that if you can.